# When I start the app first time, the username is null

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 1000;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseFirestore db;
    private static String userName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        generateUserName();

        try {
            sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if(user!=null){
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            Toast.makeText(this, userName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            intent.putExtra("name", userName);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }else{
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
        }
    }

    private void generateUserName(){
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        db.collection("users").document(user.getEmail())
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                userName = task.getResult().get("name").toString();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

This Activity is SplashActivity. So the app will skip this activity when the user is logged in already. but weird thing is happening in this code.
the variable `userName` get the name data of user in FireStore.
but when I start the app first time, It's null.
but then after pushing the backButton on my phone, the app shows MainActivity and the name is not null.
it's very weird. and I don't understand why it's like this.

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reread your code it won't become any weird but it's expected. You wan't get the `userName` until your `generateUserName` finished executing the following code:

```
private void generateUserName(){
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    db.collection("users").document(user.getEmail())
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            userName = task.getResult().get("name").toString();
        }
    });
}
```

You can see that you're waiting for userName inside the `OnCompleteListener` which is running **asynchronously**.

So, you need to execute your other code ***after*** you have the userName value. Something like this:

```
private void generateUserName(){
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    db.collection("users").document(user.getEmail())
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            userName = task.getResult().get("name").toString();
            doSomethingAfterFoundUserName(userName);                   
        }
    });
}

private void doSomethingAfterFoundUserName(String userName) {
  // Get current user
  // check for current user
  // etc.. 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the name of the user from the database is the same as the user name in the `FirebaseUser` object, you can simply get the user name using the following line odf code:

```
String userName = user.getDisplayName();
```

As you can see, there is no need to make an extra call to the database, in order to get the user name. This also means, one less read operation.